# openerp v7 save and new button to keep and show previously (old) fields value in view form

Tags: odoo

I have a form with a lot of fields and with two button (Save and Close and Save and New)
when Save and New button is clicked I want those previously entered fields value to be displayed.

Thank You!

Comment: a screenshot or some code would be very nice to have. are you using buttons with type=object?

Comment: @CZoellner I'm not allowed to post screenshot let me explain it with code, i have two objects, obj1 and obj2.  obj1 has four selection fields and view form. obj2 has one2many relation with obj1 then openerp brings two buttons by default (Save & Close and Save &New) and obj1 form on obj2 view , what i want is when Save & New clicked those previously selected values to visible first than showing and empty form with selection option. Thank you!

Comment: ok, i think i've understood your question now: you're adding OBJ1s to OBJ2 (one2many) while using OBJ1's form(ular) view. in that you got your 2 buttons. now you want your data, which was put in on the first OBJ1 instance to be passed as default values on the next instance. maybe thats possible by using the context, but i'll have to try that out.

Comment: you got it right @CZoellner but i think this is possible through JavaScript am i correct?

Comment: javascript is not my favourite, but the context can help you out here, but i have to try it out by myself first. but i'm out for today, hopefully i can give an answer tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

OK, my first solution (using context) didn't work out :-( but i tried another way, i dont like it very much, but it could help you out.

following my example .py:

```
from openerp.osv import orm, fields

class object_one(orm.Model):
    _name = "object.one"

    _columns = {
                'name':fields.char('Name', size=128, required=True),
                'many_ids':fields.many2many('object.many',string="Many Objects")
                }

class object_many(orm.Model):
    _name = "object.many"

    _columns = {
                'name':fields.char('Name', size=128, required=True),
                'sel':fields.selection([('1','One'),
                                        ('2','Two'),
                                        ('3','Three')],
                                       string="Selection", required=True),
                }

    def _get_sel(self, cr, uid, context={}):
        many_id = self.search(cr, uid, [('create_uid','=',uid)], context=context, order="create_date desc", limit=1)
        if many_id:
            many = self.browse(cr, uid, many_id[0], context)
            return many.sel
        return False

    _defaults = {
                 'sel':_get_sel
                 }
```

following my example .xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>
        <record id="one_form" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">one form view</field>
            <field name="model">object.one</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <form version="7.0" string="">
                    <group>
                        <field name="name" />
                        <field name="many_ids" />
                    </group>
                </form>
            </field>
        </record>
        <record id="one_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">one tree view</field>
            <field name="model">object.one</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <tree version="7.0" string="">
                    <field name="name" />
                </tree>
            </field>
        </record>
        <record id="many_form" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">many form view</field>
            <field name="model">object.many</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <form version="7.0" string="">
                    <group>
                        <field name="name" />
                        <field name="sel" />
                    </group>
                </form>
            </field>
        </record>
        <record id="many_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">many tree view</field>
            <field name="model">object.many</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <tree version="7.0" string="">
                    <field name="name" />
                    <field name="sel" />
                </tree>
            </field>
        </record>
        <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="one_tree_action">
            <field name="name">One Objects</field>
            <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
            <field name="res_model">object.one</field>
            <field name="view_type">form</field>
            <field name="view_mode">form,tree</field>
            <field name="view_id" ref="one_tree" />
        </record>
        <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="many_tree_action">
            <field name="name">Many Objects</field>
            <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
            <field name="res_model">object.many</field>
            <field name="view_type">form</field>
            <field name="view_mode">form,tree</field>
            <field name="view_id" ref="many_tree" />
        </record>
        <menuitem name="Testing Menu" id="testing_menu" />
        <menuitem name="Sub Menu" parent="testing_menu" id="sub_menu" />
        <menuitem action="one_tree_action" name="One Menu" parent="sub_menu" id="one_menu" />
        <menuitem action="many_tree_action" name="Many Menu" parent="sub_menu" id="many_menu" />
    </data>
</openerp>
```

you will see, every many-object created by an user, will have the last selection (sel) get from db. so its more of a workaround for your problem.

hope this will help you.

Comment: thanks for your help but this won't show unless the values affects the database (stored) because when the Save & New button clicked it doesn't store immediately while it keeps in memory. I thank you again!!

Comment: as i said i don't like my answer, and now i know why x.X maybe i'll find another solution :/